# How use apply for each matrix in 3-d array in R

Tags: r, arrays, apply, dimensions

If you have a function `f` that takes a matrix and returns a matrix with different dimensions. Is there a way to use R's `apply` with `f` for each matrix in an 3-d array and return an array with altered dimension.

For instance, say I have

```
f <- function(m)(m[,1:2] + m[,3:4]) / rowSums(m)
```

and the array

```
A <- array(1:40, dim = c(2,5,4))
```

Then if I interpret the dimension as index for the (2) matrices, I get on the first matrix:

```
> f1(A[1,,])
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.3437500 0.6562500
[2,] 0.3611111 0.6388889
[3,] 0.3750000 0.6250000
[4,] 0.3863636 0.6136364
[5,] 0.3958333 0.6041667
```

That is a c(5,2) matrix.
In my head I keep thinking `apply` as "do this function for each margin slice", and believe I can do:

```
> apply(A, 1, f1)
           [,1]      [,2]
 [1,] 0.3437500 0.3529412
 [2,] 0.3611111 0.3684211
 [3,] 0.3750000 0.3809524
 [4,] 0.3863636 0.3913043
 [5,] 0.3958333 0.4000000
 [6,] 0.6562500 0.6470588
 [7,] 0.6388889 0.6315789
 [8,] 0.6250000 0.6190476
 [9,] 0.6136364 0.6086957
[10,] 0.6041667 0.6000000
```

This is the results rbind'ed/stacked with dim c(10,2) where I wanted them as an c(2,5,2) array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we don't want to simplify, an option is

```
apply(A, 1, function(x) list(f1(x)))
```

---

Or convert to `array`

```
array(apply(A, 1, f1), dim = c(2, 5, 2))
```

Based on the results with `f1(A[1,,])`, the output can be

```
array(apply(A, 1, f1), dim = c(5, 2, 2))
```

Comment: Are you saying that it is because the dims are simplified ? Then - if I really wanted the array as result, I would need to feed the result into `array` keeping track on the dimenstion.